# When I am trying to times a number it just duplicates it by the amount of times. PYTHON

Tags: python

```
#Initialising Variables
inputISBN = input("What is your 10 digit ISBN number? ")
itemInList = 0
timesNumber = 11
listISBN = []
timesISBN = []
#Checking if the input is only numbers
if len(inputISBN) == 10 and inputISBN.isdigit() :
    while itemInList < 10 :
      listISBN.append(inputISBN[itemInList])
      itemInList = itemInList + 1
    print(listISBN)
    itemInList = 0
    while itemInList < 10 :
        num = listISBN[itemInList]
        int(num)
        timesISBN.append(num * timesNumber)
        itemInList = itemInList + 1
        timesNumber = timesNumber - 1
    print(timesISBN)
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

HALP it just prints the input number 11 times then 10 times ARRAGGH
Sorry but there is nothing more to say and i ahve to add more details.
This code is meant to times your input by 11 then 10 and so on but it only duplicates the number by that many. I dont understand why this does not work

Comment: make sure that you are multiplying `numbers` not `strings`

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the return value of the `int()` call; the `num` value is otherwise not affected:

```
num = listISBN[itemInList]
num = int(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way of doing this:

```
>>> inputISBN=input("What is your 10 digit ISBN number? ")
What is your 10 digit ISBN number? 1203874657
>>> if(len(inputISBN)==10 and inputISBN.isdigit()):
...     timesISBN = [int(i)*j for i,j in zip(inputISBN,range(11,1,-1))]
...     print(timesISBN)
... else:
...     print("Invalid input")
... 
[11, 20, 0, 24, 56, 42, 20, 24, 15, 14]
```